# C#/XAML Tapped event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

When we have a situation like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Tapped="Grid1_OnTapped"> 
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Tapped="Grid2_OnTapped">
        <!-- ... -->
           ...  
                     <Grid x:Name="Grid_n" Tapped="Grid_n_OnTapped">
                          <!-- ... -->
                     </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When the user taps on `Grid_n` the `Grid_n_OnTapped` event method is called, but all event methods of all parent grids is called too. So my question is, is it possible to somehow prevent that, i.e. "Grid1_OnTapped" must be called only when tap's location is in `Grid1`'s area and not on his child's/sub child's area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `e.Handled = true` (where `e` is `TappedRoutedEventArgs`) in `Grid_n_OnTapped` event handler - it will prevent bubbling event to the element parent.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to build around that issue and simply check if the original source is correct:

```
// Deny first
if ((e.OriginalSource as Grid) != this.Grid_n)
    return;
// Normal handler starts here.
```

Comment: the thing is that the sender in any `Grid_X_OnTapped` is always that `Grid_X`.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I made a mistake. I actually posted what I didn't want to post (not really my day today..). You have to check for the original source. I edited the answer. This code works.

Comment: This answer is also wrong. Because `e.OriginalSource` can be another control than Grid, e.g. `TextBlock` or `Image`

Comment: Sure it can be. You would have to add some type checking as well. If you're looking for the deactivation of the event chain, then @fex's answer is probably the way to go here.